# KDB C API: exit from the subscription to a ticker plant loop

Tags: c, api, kdb

Following the [documentation](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/capi/#subscribing-to-a-tickerplant-data-feed) on the KX web-site, one can implement the following loop consuming messages published by a KDB ticker plant:

```c
while(1) 
{
    K response = k(handle, (S) 0); 
    if(!response) break;
    // do something with 'response'
    r0(response);
}
```

How can one stop consuming messages from the ticker plant and exit the loop (for example, after a specific time during the day) without having to manually kill the C application if the ticker plant stopped publishing any messages? For example, is it possible to set a timeout to the `k` function call? Or, can I publish some special message to the ticker plant from another thread, which would make me to receive `response==0` from the `k` function? Or, maybe, the loop can be re-implemented using asynchronous call to the `k` function? When the ticker plant does not publish any messages, the call to the `k` function never finishes.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What operating system are you using?  I'm not sure if this library is open source or not; if it is, could you post a link to the source of `k` function you are calling so we can see how it works?

Comment: I am using Linux (RHEL). The library is not an open source, but the header is: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/c/c/k.h One idea I have to try to disconnect from the ticker plant from another thread. Checking it now...

Comment: Disconnecting from the ticker plant from another thread seems to do the trick.

Comment: @S.V please post your solution as an answer to your question and accept it, if it helped you solve your issue.